# 2D barcode generation issue in Java

Tags: java, itext, barcode

I am generating barcodes using iText API, everything looks good when it is linear barcodes when it is 2D barcodes then barcodes are placed into pdf document as images, hence reducing the quality of the barcode on low resolution printers and unable to scan the barcode. Below is the code

```
BarcodePDF417 pdf417 = new BarcodePDF417();
    String text = "BarcodePDF417 barcode";
    pdf417.setText(text);
    Image img = pdf417.getImage();        
    document.add(img);
```

Now i am look for an alternative to draw barcode and i found palceBarcode method which might favor to the requirement.

I have seen the below code in BarcodePDF417 class in itext source and could not able to find out the way how to use it

```
public void placeBarcode(PdfContentByte cb, BaseColor foreground, float moduleHeight, float moduleWidth) {
    paintCode();
    int stride = (bitColumns + 7) / 8;
    cb.setColorFill(foreground);
    for (int k = 0; k < codeRows; ++k) {
        int p = k * stride;
        for (int j = 0; j < bitColumns; ++j) {
            int b = outBits[p + j / 8] & 0xff;
            b <<= j % 8;
            if ((b & 0x80) != 0) {
                cb.rectangle(j * moduleWidth, (codeRows - k - 1) * moduleHeight, moduleWidth, moduleHeight);
            }
        }
    }
    cb.fill();
}
```

Can anyone suggest the way to use the above method?

I have written code like below but getting dark page as a whole.

```
Rectangle pageSize = new Rectangle(w * 72, h * 72);
    Document doc = new Document(pageSize, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, getOutputStream());
    doc.open();
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
    BarcodePDF417 pf = new BarcodePDF417();
    pf.setText("BarcodePDF417 barcode");
    pf.getImage();
    Rectangle rc = pf.getBarcodeSize();
    pf.placeBarcode(cb, BaseColor.BLACK, rc.getHeight(), rc.getWidth());
    doc.close();
```

Comment: Generate the barcode with 2x normal resolution and then place it as a scaled image of 1x width/height. it will most likely look better. Just as it is done [here in sample code](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=297).

Comment: @Dariusz - thank you, i have been working with thermal printer with 203 dpi, which very hard to raster the barcode as image such a printer, if we force to raster the image then barcode will be printed but not scanned.

Comment: @Dhorrairaajj Some of the assumption that you made in your question are wrong. I'll make you an example that explains why.

Comment: @Bruno Lawagie -- Thanks for the reply, module width and height passing to placeBarcode is wrong, if pass 1 as width and height then it is working, lack of java doc even for public method

Comment: @Dhorrairaajj Your interpretation of the module width and the module height is wrong. It's the width and the height of the small rectangles inside the barcode. It is *not* the size of the barcode itself.

Comment: @bruno Lowagie- agreed, since there is no document for that method i assumed like that.

Comment: This example not working, the method `placeBarcode` doesnt exist in itext 5.0.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at the [BarcodePlacement](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/barcodes/BarcodePlacement) example. In this example, we create three PDF417 barcodes:

```
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
Image img = createBarcode(cb, "This is a 2D barcode", 1, 1);
document.add(new Paragraph(
    String.format("This barcode measures %s by %s user units",
       img.getScaledWidth(), img.getScaledHeight())));
document.add(img);
img = createBarcode(cb, "This is NOT a raster image", 3, 3);
document.add(new Paragraph(
    String.format("This barcode measures %s by %s user units",
        img.getScaledWidth(), img.getScaledHeight())));
document.add(img);
img = createBarcode(cb, "This is vector data drawn on a PDF page", 1, 3);
document.add(new Paragraph(
    String.format("This barcode measures %s by %s user units",
        img.getScaledWidth(), img.getScaledHeight())));
```

The result looks like this on the outside:

[image]

One particular barcode looks like this on the inside:

[image]

I'm adding this *inside* view to show that the 2D barcode is not added as a raster image (as was the case with the initial approach you've tried). It is a vector image consisting of a series of small rectangles. You can check this for yourself by taking a look at the [barcode_placement.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/barcode_placement.pdf) file.

Please don't be confused because I use an `Image` object. If you look at the `createBarcode()` method, you can see that the `Image` is, in fact, a vector image:

```
public Image createBarcode(PdfContentByte cb, String text,
    float mh, float mw) throws BadElementException {
    BarcodePDF417 pf = new BarcodePDF417();
    pf.setText("BarcodePDF417 barcode");
    Rectangle size = pf.getBarcodeSize();
    PdfTemplate template = cb.createTemplate(
        mw * size.getWidth(), mh * size.getHeight());
    pf.placeBarcode(template, BaseColor.BLACK, mh, mw);
    return Image.getInstance(template);
}
```

The height and the width passed to the `placeBarcode()` method, define the height and the width of the small rectangles that are drawn. If you look at the *inside* view, you can see for instance:

```
0 21 3 1 re
```

This is a rectangle with x = 0, y = 21, width 3 and height 1.

When you ask the barcode for its size, you get the number of rectangles that will be drawn. Hence the dimensions of the barcode is:

```
Rectangle size = pf.getBarcodeSize();
float width = mw * size.getWidth();
float height = mh * size.getHeight();
```

Your assumption that `size` is a size in user units is only correct if `mw` and `mh` are equal to `1`.

I use these values to create a `PdfTemplate` instance and I draw the barcode to this *Form XObject*. Most of the times, it's easier to work with the `Image` class than working with `PdfTemplate`, so I wrap the `PdfTemplate` inside an `Image`.

I can then add this `Image` to the document just like any other image. The main difference with *ordinary* images, is that this image is a vector image.

Comment: Thanks for spending time to provide clean explanation. It seems there is no placeBarcode methodofor DataMatrix barcode so i used the same placeBarcode(PDF417 barcode) method with minor changes it start working amazing. Thanks for great support

Comment: @Buno Lowagie -- updated my question with code which was draw barcode as image.

Comment: Yes, I see. That's useful for further reference, in case other people have the same question.